# Rotating map plot using basemap in python

Tags: python, gis, netcdf, matplotlib-basemap, netcdf4

I am trying to plot data from a netcdf using `Basemap` but I guess since the latitude indices are inverted I get a map that is upside down. How should I fix this? Thanks!

```
fnc = Dataset(ncfile, 'r')
lat = fnc.variables['latitude'][:]
lon = fnc.variables['longitude'][:]
level = fnc.variables['level']
mydata = fnc.variables['Data'][:]
imgplot = plt.imshow(mydata[0, 0, :, :])
imgplot.set_cmap('RdYlGn')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show
```

[image]

```
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon = -180, llcrnrlat = -90, urcrnrlon = 180, urcrnrlat= +90, resolution = 'l', epsg=4326)
x, y = m(lon, lat)
im = m.imshow(mydata[0, 0, :, :])
m.drawcoastlines()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that you're currently reading in one dimension of `Data`:

```
mydata = fnc.variables['Data'][:]
```

but later you're trying to extract slices of it as if it were 4D:

```
imgplot = plt.imshow(mydata[0, 0, :, :])
```

So, you'll want to read-in all 4 dimensions of `Data` (perhaps those are time, level, lat, lon?):

```
mydata = fnc.variables['Data'][:,:,:,:]
```

and then reverse latitudes using the `::-1` syntax:

```
imgplot.plotimshow(mydata[0, 0, ::-1, :])
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have a follow up question as well and would appreciate it if you could help me there as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38338177/how-to-remove-grey-boudary-lines-in-a-map-when-plotting-a-netcdf-using-imshow-in

Answer (score 0):

I believe that plotting command needs to be aware of the map coordinates x,y. Try to replace the

```
im = m.imshow(mydata[0, 0, :, :])
```

with

```
m.pcolormesh(x,y,mydata[0,0,:,:])
```

and it should work.