# How to remove grey boundary lines in a map when plotting a netcdf using imshow in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

Is it possible to remove the grey boundary lines around the in following map? I am trying to plotting a netcdf using `matplotlib`.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset # clarify use of Dataset
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
fnc = Dataset(ncfile, 'r')
lat = fnc.variables['latitude'][:]
lon = fnc.variables['longitude'][:]
level = fnc.variables['level'][:]
mydata = fnc.variables['Data'][0, 0, :, :]
plt.figure(figsize = (8, 4))
imgplot = plt.imshow(mydata, cmap = 'YlGn')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show
```

[image]

Edit: I think the grey values are a result of missing values/no data.

Comment: What defines `Dataset`? Because that's what knows about the country boundaries.

Comment: `Dataset` is part of the netcdf4 module. Is this what you meant to ask?

Comment: Could you post netcdf file or it is have large size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those gray boundaries are an interpolation artifact from `imshow`. To get rid of them, do:

```
imgplot = plt.imshow(mydata, cmap = 'YlGn', interpolation='none')
```

Or plot through `Basemap` and control drawing explicitly, as in [this example](http://joehamman.com/2013/10/12/plotting-netCDF-data-with-Python/).

Comment: Thanks! I have a follow up question that is probably linked to interpolation so I am adding a link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340731/how-to-increase-contrast-when-plotting-a-netcdf-using-imshow-in-matplotlib