# How to increase contrast when plotting a netcdf using imshow in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

Is there a way to increase contrast when plotting data (from a netcdf) using imshow? In ArcMap this can be done using the 
['stretch' function](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/stretch-function.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_51BA1FD553D7414E99437464CC363E43) but I would like a solution using matplotlib.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
fnc = Dataset(ncfile, 'r')
lat = fnc.variables['latitude'][:]
lon = fnc.variables['longitude'][:]
level = fnc.variables['level'][:]
mydata = fnc.variables['Data'][0, 0, :, :]
plt.figure(figsize = (8, 4))
imgplot = plt.imshow(mydata, cmap = 'YlGn')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show
```

Current output:

[image]

What I would like (a '2.5 standard deviation stretch'):

[image]

Comment: You either scale your data or define (or choose) a new colorbar. This isn't a netcdf question. `imshow` accepts a `matplotlib.colors.Normalization` instance as an argument: see http://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html .

Answer (score 0):

Try two arguments of the `imshow` function:

```
plt.imshow(mydata, cmap = 'YlGn', interpolation = 'sinc', vmin = 0, vmax = 0.1)
```

The documentations:

https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html
https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html